# How to automate a condition based on values of one column to mutate new columns in r

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data frame, `dat`, and I wanted to add two columns `d1` and `d2` based on the condition of `c1` column which represent year in this case. `d1` should be the same min value across each year, while `d2` should be max value repeated across all values with same year.

I tried the below syntax which did the job, but I was wondering if I could write it without mentioning each year specifically. For instance, if I had a data frame of many years, the syntax could **automate** the procedure for each year (min of each year repeated in `d1`, and max of each year for `d2`)

Would appreciate any help on this.

```
set.seed(3)
c1 <- sample(x = c("2010","2011"), size = 10, replace = T)
c2 <- sample(x = c(1:5), size = 10, replace = T)
c3 <- sample(x = c(6:10), size = 10, replace = T)

dat <- data.frame(c1, c2, c3)

dat %>%
  mutate(
    d1 = ifelse(c1 == 2010, min(subset(dat, c1 == 2010)$c2), 
                min(subset(dat, c1 == 2011)$c2)),
    d2 = ifelse(c1 == 2010, max(subset(dat, c1 == 2010)$c3), 
                max(subset(dat, c1 == 2011)$c3))
  )
```

Comment: I am not too sure about the expected output. Grouped by year, you want the min of `c2` and the max of `c3`? `library(dplyr); dat |> mutate(d1 = min(c2), d2 = max(c3), .by = c1)` does this.

Comment: If you have multiple years, won't you overwrite the year-specific minima in `d1`?  Please provide your expected output.

Comment: Thanks @Friede. That was what I am looking for. To write the synyax without mentioning the year specifically, like 2010, but rather as a general. This was easy by group_by. Sorry if my question wasn't clear enough.

Comment: Then I will move my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered the question in a comment as follows.

> Thanks @Friede. That was what I am looking for

**Answer**

```
library(dplyr) 
dat |> mutate(d1 = min(c2), 
              d2 = max(c3), 
              .by = c1)
```

**Note**

OP's data example.

```
set.seed(3)
c1 <- sample(x = c("2010","2011"), size = 10, replace = T)
c2 <- sample(x = c(1:5), size = 10, replace = T)
c3 <- sample(x = c(6:10), size = 10, replace = T)
dat <- data.frame(c1, c2, c3)
```

Comment: Also `group_by` before `mutate` would work.